# Right-hand/left-hand jump discontinuity confusions

Tags: continuity

I have troubles understanding the definitions for right-hand/left-hand jump discontinuities.

As given in e.g.

https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:5850/FULLTEXT01.pdf

$f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ monotone on $[a,b]$, $c \in [a,b]$.

**right-hand jump:**

given $c \in [a,b)$

$$\sigma_c^+=f(c+0)-f(c)$$

**left-hand jump:**

given $c \in (a,b]$

$$\sigma_c^-=f(c)-f(c-0)$$

These are intuitively $=0$? But then the author does a proof where he claims that for $f$ increasing **these would be positive**?

What's the meaning of $f(c+0)$ or $f(c-0)$? Aren't these same as $f(c)$?

Comment: About your last question, look at the bottom of the 3rd page of the pdf. $f(c+0)$ is *not* $f(c)$, it's a notation for $\lim_{h\to 0} f(c+h)$.

Comment: @Al.G.Yes this clears it. The notation is perhaps a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notations $f(c+0)$ and $f(c-0)$ are first introduced in Theorem 1.0.2,
which says (in part)

> Then $f(c+ 0)$ and $f(c−0)$ $\color{red}{^1}$ exists

where I have colored the footnote number $\color{red}{1}$ red for emphasis.
If you look at footnote number $1$ at the bottom of the same page,
you may see that it says

> $^1$ We denote the right-hand and left-hand limits
> $$\lim_{h\to0}f(c+h) =f(c+ 0) \qquad \lim_{h\to0}f(c−h) =f(c−0)$$
> where $h$ tends to $0$ from the positive side.

So these somewhat unusual notations are related to the function $f$ but are not the same as the function $f.$
You can mentally substitute the left-hand side of each of these definitions whenever you see the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is increasing, then $\sigma_c^+ \ge 0$ and $\sigma_c^- \ge 0$.

We have $\sigma_c^+ = 0 \iff \lim_{x \to c+0}=f(c)$ and $\sigma_c^- = 0 \iff \lim_{x \to c-0}=f(c)$.

Comment: What are you taking limits of?

Comment: Why does $f$ increasing imply that?